# How to return xmlData using datareader when Store Procedure data is xml?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linux, stored-procedures

I have a small MS SQL table. And I also create a basic store procedure that use only simple "select" case. The store procedure returns the xml data as I expected.

```
**-- This is my MS SQL Store Procedure**
USE [PRIMEWORLD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getInstitutionCodes] 

@Data XML  OUTPUT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE  @xml XML 
     
    SET @xml = (SELECT *
                FROM   tbl_Institution_Codes
                for XML RAW) 
     
    SET @Data = @xml 
  END
```

**My Store Procedure result is:**

```
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="BELS095" CorporateName="CityHall Water City1" CorporateCategory="CityHall" />
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="BELS200" CorporateName="CityHall Water City2" CorporateCategory="CityHall" />
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="BELS777" CorporateName="CityHall Water City3" CorporateCategory="CityHall" />
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="BELT012" CorporateName="CityHall Traffic City3" CorporateCategory="CityHall" />
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="SAT" CorporateName="SatPan1" CorporateCategory="TV/Radio" />
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="NYU" CorporateName="New York University" CorporateCategory="Universities" />
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="TAx" CorporateName="TaxOffice" CorporateCategory="Goverment" />
<tbl_Institution_Codes CorporateCode="GSM" CorporateName="LmTell" CorporateCategory="Gsm" />
```

Now I need to get this data into my embedded linux terminal. I use c sharp web api. My problem is how to return xml data which comes from store procedure using web api to my embedded linux terminal?

```
-- This is my web api function

private string GetInstitutionCodesstring id)
        {
            try
            {
                string mFunctionId = id;
                string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PRIMEWORLD;User ID=sa;Password=*****";

                SqlConnection cnn;
                cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                cmd.CommandText = "getInstitutionCodesstring";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = cnn;
                cnn.Open();

                string rInstitutionValues = null;

                using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // **Question:** How to add the xml values into string
                         rInstitutionValues = reader.ReadOuterXml();
                    }
                }
                // **Question:** How to return xml values
                return rInstitutionValues;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "";
                msg = ex.StackTrace;
                return "";
            }
        }
```

There are 2 question above c sharp code. I nede help to return the xml data back to embedded linux terminal. **Simply, I need to return to My Store Procedure result to embedded linux terminal using DataReader in my web api**? Anyone

Thanks

Update: Working part.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   string myString = reader.GetString(0);
   returnXmlData = returnXmlData + myString;
};

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(returnXmlData);
reader.Close();
cnn.Close();

return returnXmlData;
```

I use XmlDocument to return the xml data using web api to embedded linux terminal

Comment: This is not answerable. What does the XML look like that gets returned and what do you want to see in the string as output of that method. Please provide example of both (so input xml and expected output)

Comment: @rene thank you. I update my question. Simply, I need to return to My Store Procedure result to embedded linux terminal using DataReader in my web api.

Comment: Can't you just do `return XDocument.Load(reader).ToString();`?